# Writing a cleaner version of code to improve readability

Tags: r, dataframe, inner-join, data-cleaning

I am fairly new to R and I am hoping to know if there is a cleaner way of writing the code below. Basically, I am dropping a few duplicates from df1 and appending them to df2. I am then joining the values from count_df to df2 and renaming certain columns in df2.

I would really like to do all of this under a single code block as opposed to the way I have done it below. However, I keep running very different errors every time I try to put this all under a single code block. This is just a single instance, but I have had to do this multiple times already in my code. I would greatly appreciate any input on how to improve the code below. Thank you!

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  distinct(ID, Temp, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(n())

df2 <- df2 %>%
  inner_join(count_df, by = c("ID" = "ID"))

df2 <- df2 %>%
  rename(unique_dps = `n()`,inital_dps = n)
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have this in the same `%>%`

```
library(dplyr)
count_df %>%
        add_count(ID, Temp) %>% 
        rename(unique_dps = n)
```